# CakePHP Model Name as Variable

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I am using CakePHP 2. We can access a Model named 'Setting' as `$this->Setting->find('all')` however, how could i make the 'Setting' value a Variable. Something like

```
$modelName = 'Setting';
$data = $this->{$modelName}->find('all');
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `$data = $this->$modelName->find('all');` it should work

Comment: Thanks @zzlalani. This worked perfect. Can you post it as answer so that i can accept it. It might be helpful to our friends looking for such answers

Comment: although you have your answer already, but have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/19153680/829533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work this way

```
$modelName = 'Setting';
$data = $this->$modelName->find('all');
```

no need to use `{` `}` curly braces

Answer (score 1):

I use to initiate my main model like this

```
$modelClass = $this->Mymodel;
```

And I use model functions like this

```
$modelClass->id  = $id;
$modelClass->save($this->request->data);
$this->request->data = $modelClass->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));
```

I hope that will work for you